# Реферальная система без регистрации

Tags: mysqli, php

Не могу понять, как сделать реферальную систему без регистрации, то есть данных 0. Допустим, пользователь заходит на сайт и для него генерируется ссылка и привязывается к его IP адресу. Когда по его ссылке заходят определенное кол-во человек, то происходит какое-то действие. Объясните как это реализовать, что потребуется ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Какие действия будут совершаться при заходе по сгенерированной ссылке? Как реферер ( человек по чьей ссылке зайдут на сайт) будет отслеживать заходы по его ссылке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и осуществите регистрацию, где вместо логина будет IP-адрес, а сам процесс регистрации будет происходить при входе на сайт автоматически без всяких полей ввода и кнопок "зарегистрироваться" и т.д.
НО! У многих людей динамический IP-адрес, а привязка к чему-то непостоянному - своего рода глупость.